# Memory management in Picasso

Tags: android, bitmap, garbage-collection, picasso

I had a few questions about Picasso.
1. I saw [here](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/LruCache.java#L30) that the memory cache used by Picasso is just a LinkedHashMap which holds a strong reference to the Bitmaps. Shouldn't it have a WeakReference or a SoftReference to the Bitmaps? If not, then how will the images get cleared from cache when memory becomes low and GC runs?

2.In a heap dump collected from an app after closing the app on back-press and running the GC, i can still see the instances of `Picasso.LruCache` (image attached below) with Bitmaps in it. Why is this `LruCache` instance retained? Because its occupying a lot of memory.

[image]

3.Also Also i can see a lot of instances of PicassoDrawable class. That too after GC run
[image]